# How to batch convert all Camera Raw 2 files to jpg?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know how to do this using image processing in Adobe Bridge, but I want to also adjust the image brightness and levels and also place a watermark on the images.

Is there a method to do this in Photoshop or Bridge?

Comment: Wouldn't each individual image need it's own levels and brightness adjustment? Is it a good idea to batch processes images all with the same settings?

Comment: Hi scott if the image count is few then its fine but i have more than 450 images, if i do manually it take more time, what do u think?

Comment: Well, it depends upon the quality you are seeking. There's no shortcut to excellent work in most cases.

Comment: i agree to you, but in my case it would be 65% quality is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an action to do what you want (adjust brightness, create text layer for watermark etc. and save), then go the file > automate > batch dialog and run it on all your files.

Comment: hi John, I knew this before, but can you tell me whether the watermark will be adjusted depending on the image size?

Comment: @Bala Not sure if it can. I don't do a lot of actions. Maybe someone will chime in, but more advanced stuff typically falls into the realm of scripting. One workaround that may (or may not) be acceptable is to image processor your images to the same size first.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be working on each particular photo, then you should consider [Adobe Lightroom](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop_lightroom) (you can download a trial and see if you like it).

You could use Photoshop or Bridge, but you will find you can do much more with a program that was actually created for this need. It's Photoshop for photography postproduction. I think the best thing is that it can handle ridiculously large files and it kind of has Bridge included in it, because you can manage them inside the program.

You can do [batch processing in Lightroom](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3403333) too, you use the Presets.

> Presets are very similar to Adobe Photoshop's actions. They allow
>   users to one run a program and then the settings for that program will
>   be applied to all the photos in a set. Lightroom presets work a little
>   different than Photoshop actions since they don't need to be created
>   manually. ([source](http://www.steves-digicams.com/knowledge-center/how-tos/photo-software/lightroom-how-to-batch-your-settings.html#b))

Some screenshots that show the file management and the editing tools:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi yisela, i did not know about lightroom, thanks for your answer, anyway it helps anyone, i will also going to try this.